# Center a div that contains another div with inline-block

Tags: html, css

How do i center a main DIV, within which contains another div that has an inline-block.

```
<div class="newdiv>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><div class="pinterest-hover social-slide"></div></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><div class="instagram-hover social-slide"></div></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><div class="reddit-hover social-slide"></div></a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><div class="rss-hover social-slide"></div></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stumbleupon-hover {
    background-image: url('icons/stumbleupon-hover.png');
}

.social-slide {
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    border:3px solid;
    /*margin: 10px;*/
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;
}

.social-slide:hover {
    background-position: 0px -48px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
    /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);*/
}

div.newdiv {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Basically I want to center the social icons via `newdiv`
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uWaPy/

Comment: please clarify your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
div.new-div {
    text-align:center;
}
```

You had a missing " in the `div.new-div`.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uWaPy/2/).

IE < 8 doesn't like `inline-block`, there's a hack :

```
.social-slide {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    *zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: Cool, it worked! However, I removed the width and kept the margin in place. giving it widths is actually misleading I believe as its not actually being centered won't you agree ?

Comment: Thanks for the updated hack. I would like to know why is it that some cases where text-align:center doesn't work (and you have to use margin:0 auto;) and in some cases it does?

Comment: Nope, you're mixing block and inline-block ! To center a block, you'd have to set a width and a margin. Inline-blocks are "like" text items and behave like it :). [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/uWaPy/5/) for example, I've set a width and a margin on the container, which is displayed as a block.

Answer (score 0):

```
.newdiv 
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width:900px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `text-align:center;` to `div.newdiv`

Also you are missing a " in your html.

```
<div class="newdiv>
```

should be:

```
<div class="newdiv">
```

Comment: My mistake on that, was deleting div names, must had misplaced the " in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.newdiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

just edit this code. And in your div tag, it should be `<div class="newdiv">`